# How to make layout like Instagram Story with native Android?

Tags: android, facebook, instagram, instagram-story

I'm building an app with requirement like Instagram Story/ Facebook Story.

There's a video / image on background , and an editText which stick on bottom of layout.

If i use **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing"** , when my keyboard is show , my layout is same still.
But my edittext is not pushed up.

But, if i use **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"** , when my keyboard is shown , then my layout is going to pushed up and shrink.

I expect when keyboard up : I need to make video / image stand still on behind(not shrinked and pushed up), and edittext is placed on above keyboard.

How i should set my layout?

Comment: I think this is what are you looking for... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297918/implement-story-reply-like-instagram-android