# Implement story reply like Instagram Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview, instagram-story

With Instagram when a user clicks on an EditText view the next scenario occurs:

- an emoji view is displayed [Not necessary in my case]
- story still maintains its width & height [Not being resized] [Required]
- keyboard is opened [Required]
- seems like view has a transparent background

For my case when I used `ADJUST_RESIZE` I got the view displayed properly but ImageView of story must have **scaleType** [**fitXY** or **centerCrop**] which has a bad UI with some images, if I did not make it with these scaleTypes ImageView will be resized and have margins beside it.

### When not use ScaleTypes[fixtXY, centerCrop] while keyboard is opened:

[image]

### while keyboard is closed:

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code for particular layout and activity

Comment: a simplified test code added

https://pastebin.com/UMsvAVZM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make ImageView with a fixed size.

```
private fun makeViewFullWidth(view: View) {
        val point = Point()
        // point will be populated with screen width and height 
        activity?.windowManager?.defaultDisplay?.getSize(point)
        val param = view.layoutParams
        param.width = point.x
        param.height = point.y
        view.layoutParams = param
    }
```

you can also check this [article](https://mahmoud-mabrok.medium.com/maintain-view-from-resizing-while-use-adjust-resize-915676c1c5e5)